# Creating a function in mysql with if exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a function in MySQL like so, bu tI am getting a syntax error at the if exists line:

I think I am doing something slightly off as a result of translation from MS SQL server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(input_field INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5) 
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Teaches WHERE courseid = input_field)
    RETURN 'True'
    RETURN 'false'
END;
```

**UPDATE

The solution I found based on the answer from @SK Jajoriya

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction2(input_field INTEGER)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Teaches WHERE courseid = input_field) THEN
        RETURN 'True';
    ELSE
            RETURN 'False';
    END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(input_field INTEGER)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(5) 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Teaches WHERE courseid = input_field) THEN
        RETURN 'True'
    ELSE
            RETURN 'false'
    END IF;
END;
```

In your case, the `if` statement not closed

Comment: This gives me a syntax error on the return 'True' line. It underlines true and says missing semicolon. However, adding semicolon does not help.

Comment: How about the 'else'? So far no luck.

Comment: It makes sense, however, still the same error. Perhaps it's due to mySQL version?  'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE  RETURN 'false'     END IF' at line 6'

Comment: Which version are you using of mysql server ??

Comment: Oh, I found it. I needed to add ; behind each line and start with delimiter $$. and end with END $$

Answer (score 0):

IF should be finished with END IF
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html
But in your case it's better to

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(input_field INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5) 
BEGIN
   DECLARE res VARCHAR(5);
   SET res = IF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Teaches WHERE courseid = input_field LIMIT 1),'true','false');
   RETURN res;
END;
```

here is a fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFkXXDpqVjn6AjYkXx3EYM/0

Comment: This gices me a syntax error. Does it return the true/false?

Comment: Oh i forgot this is a function, so you must deal with RETURN statement.